# Android FrameLayout 'tabcontent' not available in activity?

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I'm trying to change the activity of a tabview and i'm trying to access the framelayout entitled 'tabcontent'.

I keep getting the error:

```
tabcontent cannot be resolved or is not a field.
```

Even though it is present in my .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </FrameLayout>

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0" >
            </TabWidget>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dip"
            android:background="@drawable/attendance" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
            android:background="@drawable/sched" />
    </FrameLayout>

</TabHost>
```

I am calling it here:

```
//on Create
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
        setTabs() ;

        //Sets the visibility of the attendance and schedule buttons to invisible

        Button attend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button sched = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        attend.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        sched.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        contentviewlayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabcontent); <--ERROR
        contentviewparams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

I don't know why this is happening...I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: `android.R.id.tabcontent`. Please don't prefix your question's title with Android, the tag at the bottom is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `android.R.id.tabcontent`, because you are importing 'your.app.package.R', not android.R :)